# Tapered fork into 44mm head tube?

Tags: mountain-bike, fork

I have a MTB Ghost SE 2000 frame which has a 1 1/8" head tube. I just measured it and it has a 44mm diameter top and bottom.

I want to replace the stock fork. However it is hard to find non-tapered forks at a good price. My question is, is it possible to put 1,5" tapered fork into this specific head tube? Maybe with some special headset?

[image]

Bike detail: http://www.ghost-bikes.com/bikes-2013/bike-detail/se-2000/

Comment: Be careful with this option, you may find yourself spending more than it would cost for a 1 1/8 fork by the time you purchase a tapered fork, headset and get it fitted. Also it may be difficult to get a tapered 9mm QR fork, I think like 1 1/8 forks they're becoming more difficult to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Cane Creek makes a [headset bottom](http://store.canecreek.com/p/40-ec44-40-bottom-assembly?pp=8) for exactly this problem. I've used it on my MTB and it has worked just fine for over year. It does require that the original frame use zero stack or interior headset. But it looks like yours does.

Note: in the general case with a true 1-1/8" ( i.e. 34mm interior diameter, exterior headset cups), there isn't enough interior space to use a tapered fork.

From the Cane Creek Headset FAQ.

*Cane Creek was the first headset company to offer a tapered solution for 1-1/8" head-tubes. Called XX-44, this bottom assembly enabled the use of 1-1/8" to 1.5" tapered forks on straight, 44mm head-tubes. This gave consumers more options, and frame designers more flexibility when creating the perfect ride.
Due to the popularity of the design, the EC44/40 (External Cup for 44mm head-tube, 40mm crown race seat) Bottom is now available in both the class-leading 40-Series and the premium 110-Series of headsets. This tapered solution fits 44mm head-tubes only; a "traditional" 1-1/8", 34mm version is not available.
Please note: Nominal insertion bore depth for 44mm head-tubes is 9mm. EC44/40 requires an insertion depth of 15mm. Park Tool Reamer 788 should be used with the supplied spacer to reach the 15mm bore depth for EC44/40 Bottoms.*

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Can you point me to product/specification page for this adapter?

Comment: http://store.canecreek.com/p/40-ec44-40-bottom-assembly?pp=8

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue with wanting to keep our old frames and ante up with a beefed out fork is hard.  If you do in fact want the upgrade, try Aliexpress.com for 1 1/8 steerer tubes and old skewer axle options that are hard to find without buying a whole new bike.  I purchased one fork, instead of the "Tapered fork Overhaul" and just bought a new 1 1/8 headset along with it. Works great, and cheap. Lots of fork options too, spring, gas, 27.5 650B, whatever your looking for, they got it, cheap.

http://www.aliexpress.com/item/SIEG-130mm-travel-super-weight-magnesium-alloy-1-5kg-air-suspension-bicycle-fork/32213406008.html